# Do people who have rejected your friend requests still show up in "People you may know" on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

I don't remember whether I sent a particular person on Facebook a friend request. The option to add them as a friend is open which either means I did and they rejected it, or I didn't. I don't want to send them another one If I did already. They still show up in my "People you may know" list. Would they still show up if I they rejected my friend request?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, they will not show up in your *People you may know* list. Because when a person rejects your friend request, you will not have the option to add them as friend again. So, Facebook doesn't show their profiles in your *People you may know* list.

But they will have the option to add you as a friend, so probably your profile will show up in their *People you may know* list.